# How to set up different responses for the same request to MockServer?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot-test, mockserver

i'm having an issue when setting up the MockServerClient for multiple responses with the exact same request.

I read that with expectations with "Times" this might be done, but i coulnd't make it work with my scenario.

If you call the service with this JSON (twice):

```
{
    "id": 1
}
```

The first response should be "passed true", the second "passed false"

Response 1:

```
{
    "passed":true
}
```

Response 2:

```
{
    "passed":false
}
```

I set up the first request, but how do i set the second one?

```
import com.nice.project.MyService;
import com.nice.project.MyPojo;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockserver.integration.ClientAndServer;
import org.mockserver.matchers.TimeToLive;
import org.mockserver.matchers.Times;
import org.mockserver.model.Header;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.contains;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockserver.integration.ClientAndServer.startClientAndServer;
import static org.mockserver.model.HttpRequest.request;
import static org.mockserver.model.HttpResponse.response;

@SpringBootTest    
public class Tests{
    
    private static final int PORT = 9998;

    private static ClientAndServer mockServer;

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @BeforeAll
    public void init(){
        mockServer = startClientAndServer(PORT);
        mockServer
            .when(
                request()
                    .withPath(testUrlValidateTransactionOk).withMethod(HttpMethod.POST.name())
                    .withHeaders(
                        new Header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString())
                    )
                    .withBody(contains("\"id\":\"1\""))
                ).respond(
            response().withStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                .withHeaders(
                    new Header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString())
                )
                .withBody("{\"passed\":true}"));

        // What do i set here? Or in the snippet before by chaining?
        // mockServer.when()...

    }

    @Test
    void t1{
        //myService will internally call the MockServer

        //FIRST CALL -> Pass
        MyPojo p = myService.call(1);

        assertThat(p.isPassed()).isEqualTo(Boolean.TRUE);

        //SECOND CALL -> No Pass
        MyPojo p2 = myService.call(1);
        assertThat(p2.isPassed()).isEqualTo(Boolean.FALSE);

    }
}
```

Dependencies (relevant):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.nice.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>testing</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>Testing</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <httpclient.version>4.5.13</httpclient.version>
        <mock-server.version>5.11.2</mock-server.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>               
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>   
        
        <!--HTTP CLIENT-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!--TEST-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockserver-netty</artifactId>
            <version>${mock-server.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mock-server</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockserver-client-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mock-server.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>       

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @DV82XL Hey sorry for the delay, i needed to solve many other things at work, but i used your answer until i found in the documentation the "Times" parameter for exactly when i needed. Thank you for the help. I posted the official documentation way to approach this problem for future developers.

Comment: Great, glad you solved your problem! Just to be clear, did my solution work? It looks like we're doing the same thing, except I wrapped `mockServer.when().respond()` in a method and you added `Times.exactly(1)`. I was under the impression when `Times.exactly()` is omitted, it defaults to 1, which would make our two answers identical.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After following and diving into the documentation and testing.

I found that you can specify a "**Times**" that an expectation will be match
which solves perfectly my problem.

Link: https://www.mock-server.com/mock_server/creating_expectations.html

For every expectation i used "**Times.exactly(1)**".

The way this works is that an expectation is added to the list, when it's matched
it will be consumed, **and removed from the list**, leaving the following ones.

If no expectation is found for a call it will return a **404 from the mock server**.

Link for examples from documentation:
https://www.mock-server.com/mock_server/creating_expectations.html#button_match_request_by_path_exactly_twice

Correct code:

```
//The first call will land here, and then this expectation will be deleted, remaining the next one
mockServer
.when(
    request()
        .withPath(testUrlValidateTransactionOk).withMethod(HttpMethod.POST.name())
        .withHeaders(
            new Header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString())
        )
        .withBody(
            json("{\"id\":1}",
                MatchType.ONLY_MATCHING_FIELDS)),
        Times.exactly(1)
    ).respond(
response().withStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
    .withHeaders(
        new Header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString())
    )
    .withBody("{\"passed\":true}"));


//After the first call this will be consumed and removed, leaving no expectations
mockServer
.when(
    request()
        .withPath(testUrlValidateTransactionOk).withMethod(HttpMethod.POST.name())
        .withHeaders(
            new Header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString())
        )
        .withBody(
            json("{\"id\":1}",
                MatchType.ONLY_MATCHING_FIELDS)),
        Times.exactly(1)
    ).respond(
response().withStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
    .withHeaders(
        new Header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString())
    )
    .withBody("{\"passed\":false}"));
```

Comment: We can use Times.once(), if expect to run mockServer with this response exactly 1 time.

Comment: For some reason, @ Springboottest turns out to be better alternative in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a sequence of responses by wrapping the when/request/response behavior in a method and calling it multiple times, like this:

```java
private void whenValidateTransactionReturn(boolean isPassed) {
    mockServer
        .when(
            request()
                .withPath(testUrlValidateTransactionOk)
                .withMethod(HttpMethod.POST.name())
                .withHeaders(
                    new Header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString()))
                .withBody(contains("\"id\":\"1\"")))
        .respond(
            response()
                .withStatusCode(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                .withHeaders(
                    new Header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString()))
                .withBody("{\"passed\":" + isPassed + "}"));
  }
```

Then you can call this method multiple times:

```java
@Test
void testValidationFailsSecondTime() {
    whenValidateTransactionReturn(true);
    whenValidateTransactionReturn(false);
    //
    // Test logic
    //
    // mockServer.verify(...);
}
```